# How to query into 2 columns the same field?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have have 2 tables:

```
USER(uid, uname);
ITEM(iid, description);
TRANSACTION(buyer, seller, item);
```

`transaction.buyer` and `transaction.seller` references `user.uid`.
`transaction.item` references `item.iid`

How can I query the name of the buyer and seller of a transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two joins:

```
select t.*, b.uname as buyerName, s.uname as sellerName
from transaction t join
     user b
     on t.buyer = b.uid join
     user s
     on t.seller = s.uid
```

Comment: But won't this result in 3 columns since you have 3 select fields?

Comment: @drum . . . If you only want the two names, then remove the `t.*`.  I figured you wanted other transaction details as well.

Comment: I see, wasn't sure if it'll affect the query if it is removed.